# accessing whether a value is inside an Object or not

Tags: javascript, object

how can i know if a value is in my object in Js,
I don't know how to explain it exactly but I hope the code simplifies it for you

```
let object = {
  1: hey
  2: hi
  3: hello
}
let exist = object.value("hello")
console.log(exist) //should print true
```

Comment: why not change the keys/values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let object = {
  1: "hey",
  2: "hi",
  3: "hello"
}
let exist = Object.values(object).includes("hello")
console.log(exist)
```

Comment: Perfecto !  Super clean

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to check if a value is contained within an object.

A simple one is by accessing the Object.values(myObject).

Should look like this:

```
console.log(Object.values(myObject).some(elem => (elem === ('hello'))));
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
let object = {
  1: "hey",
  2: "hi",
  3: "hello"
}
   
let exists = Object.values(object).includes("hello");
console.log(exists);
exists = Object.values(object).includes("world");
console.log(exists);
```

But if you need checks like this quite often, you should probably think about a data structure better supporting that scenario ...